# jsforce working on command line but not api

Tags: javascript, jsforce

I am querying data from the data base from salesforce and it is working find with `jsforce -l http://test.salesforce.com` I then do a `.register` and a `.authorize` and then I can pull data from my salesforce database with a query language.  My .jsforce/config.json looks like

```
{
    "connections": {
        "<my_username>": {
            "accessToken": "<my_accessToken>",
            "instanceUrl": "<https://my.partial.instance.com>",
            "client": "default"
        }
    },
    "clients": {
        "default": {
            "clientId": "<myclientid>",
            "clientSecret": "<longNumber>",
            "redirectUri": "https://localhost:1111",
            "loginUrl": "https://test.salesforce.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Now i tried something like on the documentation for jsforce.

```
var jsforce = require('jsforce');
var conn = new jsforce.Connection({
  oauth2 : {
    // you can change loginUrl to connect to sandbox or prerelease env.
    loginUrl : 'https://test.salesforce.com',
    clientId : '<myclientid>',
    clientSecret : '<longNumber>',
    redirectUri : '<https://my.partial.instance.com>'
  }
});
conn.login(username, 'password'+'<id>', function(err, userInfo) {
  if (err) { return console.error(err); }
  // Now you can get the access token and instance URL information.
  // Save them to establish connection next time.
  console.log(conn.accessToken);
  console.log(conn.instanceUrl);
  // logged in user property
  console.log("User ID: " + userInfo.id);
  console.log("Org ID: " + userInfo.organizationId);
  // ...
});
```

and similar things from the website [here](https://jsforce.github.io/document/) giving me { invalid_grant: authentication failure } what am I doing wrong my stuff is correct because it is working on the command line interface.

Comment: I was not sure if this would be a better question for stackoverflow but thought it would be better here if this is the wrong place to post this please let me know.

Comment: If you already authorized via OAuth you don't need password authentication.
Just get authorized connection using `jsforce.registry.getConnection(username)`.

Comment: Thats what I am currently doing with the autherization what is wrong is oauth does not seem to be working @stomita